# How do I ensure my UI buttons scale with screen size and orientation using unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

This might be a dumb question but I'm using unity to build a double pendulum app and because not all screen sizes are the same the UI buttons get moved around and don't scale to match the phones screen size. I attached a few images to show you what I mean.

[image: App portrait at 1440 by 2560]

[image: App Landscape at 2560 by 1440]

[image: App Landscape at 2160 by 1080]

Notice how in the third image, the return button overlaps the other UI sliders. I think the issue is that the pixel distance from the top of the screen doesn't change given new orientation. Is there a way to keep the spacing proportional?

Answer (score 4):

On your canvas object, set it to Scale With Screen Size then, set the Match property to 0.5. This way the canvas will scale with both width and screen height.

If you need more info about Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions, [check here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well in your parent cancas object in the inspector,the 2end setting there a a drop down. Click it than a magical setting scale with screen wil be ther.

Comment: thanks. Everything all messed up now but I'll see if after I resale everything that does the trick

Comment: Yes just rescale set the anchors than move to your liking.